Zero Flight Experience to Light Jet Type Rating - Requirements, Feasibility, and Timeline?
Hi everyone I have read this form for a couple months I am someone who is extremely interested in getting my private pilots license. But I am curious about something if I was to at some point secure a very high paying job or come across a boat load of cash and I wanted to invest in a light jet like a Phenom 300 or a CJ3+ would it be possible, in a reasonable amount of time, to go from being a VFR pilot to a type rating for single pilot flight in one of these jets? What would the timeline look like? what are the requirements are there? My understanding is the biggest hurdle is insurance. I'm really just curious so sorry to bother everyone. I have no idea what the future holds but being able to fly one of these incredible machines would be a dream come true.

Aside from the costs, not to mention an insurance company willing to provide you hull insurance on an airplane like that, your chief difficulty is going to be building the experience and seasoning to move into high-performance jet aircraft.
I would argue for a minimum of 300 hours of total flight time before advancing onto a jet like that, with at least 50 hours of instrument and multi engine time and solid cross country experience simply to give yourself enough seasoning to be ready to move into a high-speed environment like that.
Legally to serve as Pilot In Command (PIC) on an airplane such as a CJ3, under Part 91 recreational flight operations, you are going to have to hold the following:

At least a Private Pilot’s Certificate, with an Airplane, Multi Engine Land rating.
An Instrument-Airplane Rating.
An High Altitude Airplane endorsement.
A current unrestricted type rating on the CitationJet.
A current FAA Medical Certificate, Third Class or better.

The first place to start would be obtaining a private pilot certificate with an airplane, single engine land rating.  One could attempt to obtain a PPL with an airplane multi engine land rating right off the bat, but this is inevitably more expensive and time-consuming, and, unless you own the airplane, it will be very difficult to talk a flight school into letting you solo in such an aircraft, not to mention insurance companies, so we will stick with the ASEL rating on your PPL for now. If you have the time and commitment for hard-core study, you could probably knock this out in about three months and meet all the requirements listed in part 91 to obtain a PPL.  Once that is done, you  will obtain your instrument rating.  Expect that this will consume at least another three months or so worth of serious study and at least a couple of flights a week.  When this is complete, you will be ready to obtain a multi-engine, land add-on.  This will typically require a complex and high performance airplane endorsements as well. Once that is all finished and assuming to you can keep up with the workload, your next challenge is going to be to start logging a lot of instrument flying as well as VFR flying To a variety of different airports and locations, and varying weather and night conditions.  We’re gonna have to start building experience and getting used to flying in high-speed, high density traffic environments as a preparation for moving into jet airplanes. I would say expect to spend 200 to 300 hours of time building at this point to get such experience.  Once that is complete, and you acquire a CJ3, you will begin your type rating training as well as acquire your high altitude, endorsement needed to fly those.  Once you have a CJ3 type rating, you will still need to log 25 additional hours with an authorized instructor and undergo a final practical test to have the SIC required limitation removed and be issued an unrestricted type rating in the CJ.
As of this point, you’re legally authorized to fly a CJ3 single pilot.
Your currency on the CJ3 type is only good for 12 calendar months and must be renewed with recurrent type rating training followed by another practical exam in order to maintain currency.
Bear in mind the following: Flying airplanes is an art and one that can become very dangerous to you and others if carelessness, incapacity, or neglect is demonstrated by the pilot.  You’ve reached the point that you can be a journeyman in your CJ3 flying, but you’ve got approach that with a dose of humility and realize that you’re very, very green at this stage of your flying career.  At a bare minimum, you’re going to have several hundred hours worth of additional flying on your own, setting very conservative personal minimums in regards to locations you fly the aircraft in and out of, weather minimums, crosswind, minimums, runway length minimums, etc.  As with any other hobby, start simple and work complex. You may not be ready to casually fly off to KJFK or KATL at this point but with time and practice it can happen.

Thank you so much! This is just a pipe dream of mine. I’d love to be able to go cool places with family and friends. You make fantastic points about safety and experience, it would be quite a journey to do this and do it right. While I am almost certain this dream will never come true it’s awesome to think about. Hopefully one day I can learn to fly even if I just get a basic PPL. Thank you for your time!

@FootballFan1846 to further drive home the point of cost and safety: to remain current and thus safe you would have to fly a lot more than 100 hours a year. Even with that you are most likely not as safe pilot as a professional one. For information regarding cost, safety and all that jazz, AOPA is a tremendous resource

@Jpe61 not correct

@Cloud so a private pilot flying a small jet less than 100h/year is as safe as a professional pilot?

You didn't state professional. The minimums for maintaining a PPL are well below 100 hours a year. Actually they're well under 50 hours per year!

@Cloud ... in a SEP! For a jet like the Citation I'd want to be doing at very least a hundred or so hours. What is strictly legal, and what is sensibly safe, are very very separate.
